# Inheritance and Overriding - Call Overriding SubMethod from BaseClass

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void method() {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
    Base() {
        method();
    }
};

class Sub : public Base {
public:
    virtual void method() {
        std::cout << "Sub" << std::endl;
    }

    Sub() : Base() {

    }
};

int main(void) {
    Base *b = new Sub();

    delete b;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Output: "Base"

What do i have to change to make the **Base** call the **Sub** Method instead of the Base?

This is probably a duplicate and a beginner-question, but i couldn't find an answer to this problem.

---

Also a suggestion for a better title is welcome as the current one might be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) because the standard says so.

b) philosophically, because `Sub` at this point has not had its constructor called (inherited objects are constructed in a depth-first manner), so calling `Sub`s version of `method` would surprise the author of `Sub`.